# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'executable_path' using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Error is:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'executable_path'
```

I can't see what is causing this!

```py
chrome_options = Options() #line 8
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') #line 9
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') #line 10
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') #line 11
browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options,executable_path=r'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/chromedriver.exe') #This is line 12
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/chromedriver.exe')
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'executable_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

`executable_path` is the first positional parameter defined by `Chrome`, so that's what the first positional argument `chrome_options` is bound to. Then you try to set the same parameter *again*, this time with a keyword argument. Specify both using keyword arguments:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='...')
```

or specify the path first:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

I still used a keyword argument for the options because `options` is the *third* positional parameter; `port` is the second.

Here's the [definition in question](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/13c36a9557252a10a6a0a2b531be502a04326dbf/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L28):

```
class WebDriver(ChromiumDriver):
    """
    Controls the ChromeDriver and allows you to drive the browser.
    You will need to download the ChromeDriver executable from
    http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    """

    def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=DEFAULT_PORT,
                 options=None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=DEFAULT_SERVICE_LOG_PATH,
                 chrome_options=None, service=None, keep_alive=True):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'executable_path'
```

...implies that the argument 'executable_path' was mentioned multiple times while invoking the *RemoteWebDriver*.

---

As per the [selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver) Class implementation:

```
class selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='chromedriver', port=0, options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, chrome_options=None)
```

Moreover, as per the defination of [WebDriver(RemoteWebDriver)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.html#WebDriver) for Chrome:

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
             options=None, service_args=None,
             desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None,
             chrome_options=None):
    """
    Creates a new instance of the chrome driver.

    Starts the service and then creates new instance of chrome driver.

    :Args:
     - executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
```

So, among the arguments which can be passed to invoke the *RemoteWebDriver* for ChromeDriver/Chrome `executable_path` is the first argument and also the default argument, incase the *Key* is not specified specifically.

Hence in your usecase, as you haven't mentioned the _key_for the first argument, it was considered as the *value* for `executable_path`. Then again in the second argument you have mentioned the *Key* / *Value* pair of `executable_path` again. Hence you see the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'executable_path'
```

---

### Solution

Your effective code block can be either of the following:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

Or

```
chrome_options = Options() #line 8
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/chromedriver.exe')
```